# If either U or V is dense subset of a ordered field F. Then the product UV is dense in F.

Tags: real-analysis

Let F be an ordered field. If U and V are nonempty subsets of F. If either U or V is dense in F. Then the product UV is dense in F.

Need proof or counter example.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Suppose U is dense in F. Let a<b in F. Then there exist x in U such that a<x<b. Now we have to show that there exists some y in UV such that a<y<b. But no clue to do this.

Comment: @Khuddush What form can $y$ take?

Comment: @Ningxin The set probably  UV=\{uv : u \in U and v \in V \}

Comment: Why don't you first handle the case where $U$ is dense and $V$ is a singleton set $\{v\}$. Then break that into two cases: when $v = 0$ as Mariano Suárez-Álvarez
 has already suggested, and then when $v \ne 0$. If you can solve that case, the rest is easy.

Comment: If v=0, then the  set UV=0. Is it possible to say a<0<b.